Converting resistance value to PWM using ADC
Glad to be part of the community. Currently I am working on a vehicle that no longer has the factory Powertrain Control Module, but I am wanting to keep the factory gauges.
All the gauges work except the fuel gauge. From what I understand that the resistance value comes from the sending unit in the tank and goes to the PCM. There it is converted from an analog signal to a digital out signal (PWM?) and then to the gauge.
I suppose what I'm trying to find out is if there is a module that can do this? Or if I can build a circuit to convert the signals?
If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

can you measure the existing signals into the working gauges?  It's going to be difficult to recommend a circuit to drive signals to the gauges unless you can provide a much better description of the signal details.  For example, you say "digital out PWM?" but if digital, we'd need to know the voltage level, and for PWM, what frequency and what duty cycle is min scale and what duty cycle is used for full scale.  A PWM output can also be low-pass filtered to create an analog signal, so not clear what is actually needed here.

A few lines of code running on an mcu like an Arduino nano would suffice for both tasks, which you should separate. For the input, what's the resistance when empty and when full? For the output, it's basically computing the duty cycle based on the input of rNow/(rMax-rMin) to get a 0-1 figure. Then you might have to tweak the PWM so that (for example) the min duty is 10% and the max duty is 85%, which is 75% usable, so multiply your 0-1 by 0.75 and add 0.1 to get full control and range on the guage.

You'll need to measure the analog voltage range, and need an oscilloscope to identify the output signal (levels, timing, waveform, etc.) and how it varies (e.g. what if it's serial data instead? etc.). You can also provide information on what it all is (vehicle, instruments, important ICs identifiable as being in the signal path, etc.), perhaps someone knows that particular system in intimate enough detail to solve it that way.
